# Issue with inserting values that fetched from locked rows

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I have two scripts bounded by transactions:

The first:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update product set price = 70;
SELECT SLEEP(20);
rollback;
```

The second:

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into product_order(product_id, amount, price) select id, amount, price from product;
commit;
```

The second transaction has started execute when the first one is in 'sleep' state.

So, I expected that second one will have executed during sleeping of the first transaction.
Unexpectedly the second transaction is waiting until the first one goes out from sleep state.
I know that it is something connected to row locking. But I hadn't updated the rows that included into the first transaction.

My question: What is the reason of such behaviour and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: It look like the lock will be released after the end of the transaction (You can't read the data because if the transaction fails the database will have to rollback to the previous state)

Comment: _But I hadn't updated the rows that included into the first transaction_ Oh yes you did. That update is to the Whole Table... there is no WHERE clause

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I remove product_id from 'product_oder' table and from insert clause, the insertion is executed without waiting.

Comment: I would use the innodb status monitor to investigate the locks being held that should give you a better understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It look like the lock will be released after the end of the transaction (You can't read the data because if the transaction fails the database will have to rollback to the previous state)

Before your insert you should set the sessions transaction isolation level so it can read data that are not commited:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

START TRANSACTION;
insert into product_order(product_id, amount, price) select id, amount, price from product;
COMMIT;

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Comment: Originally I have the "isolation" statement with the same value. And it didn't work

Comment: A simple select does not require a lock (unless serializable isolation level is used), therefore the exclusive lock set on the products table should not interfere with the select part of the insert ... select ... statement